# How to binary encode multi-valued categorical variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with multiple values for a certain column:

```
             my column

         0 - ["A", "B"]
         1 - ["B", "C", "D"]
         2 - ["B", "D"]
```

How Can I get a dataframe like this : (where every column takes the name of the values in "my column")

```
         "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
      0 - 1    1    0    0
      1 - 0    1    1    1
      2 - 0    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are lists in column use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df['my column'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
```

Or [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['my column']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
```

If there are strings use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with `str.get_dummies` and last if necessary remove `"` from columns names:

```
df = (df['my column'].str.strip('[]')
                     .str.get_dummies(', ')
                     .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('"')))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here's a naive implementation of dummies:

```
import pandas as pd

my_column = pd.Series([['A','B'],['B','C','D'],['B','D']])

frameA = pd.DataFrame(my_column, columns=['my_column'])
#extract all new headers from the DataFrame rows, in order:
headers = sorted(list(set([x for y in frame['my_column'] for x in y])))
#make a list of the DataFrame rows (stored as lists):
rows = [y for x in range(len(frame)) for y in frame.loc[x]]

builder = {}               #construct a dictionary to build a new DataFrame from
for header in headers:
    column = []
    for row in rows:
        if header in row:
            column.append(1)
        else:
            column.append(0)
    builder.update({header:column})

frameB = pd.DataFrame(builder)

print(frameB)
```

results in:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0 
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountVectorizer`, It is specialy designed for this purpose. It takes corpus of text and do `One-Hot Encoding` for it.

**Note** : I am using 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Tiger' Instead of 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

**Code :**

Imports :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

Method to convert elemrnts of list to string :

```
def get_string(listt):
  return ' '.join(listt)
```

Creating DataFrame from List :

```
my_column = pd.Series([['Cat','Dog'],['Dog','Cow','Tiger'],['Dog','Tiger']])
df = pd.DataFrame(my_column, columns=['my_column'])
print(df)
df['text_data'] = df.my_column.apply(get_string)
print(df)
```

Performing Text Vectorization :
    tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer( stop_words=None)
    vectorized_data = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df.text_data)

Preparing final DataFrame :

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(vectorized_data.toarray(),columns=tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(final_df)
```

**Out Put :**

Our DataFrame :

```
           my_column
0         [Cat, Dog]
1  [Dog, Cow, Tiger]
2       [Dog, Tiger]
```

DataFrame with text column:

```
           my_column      text_data
0         [Cat, Dog]        Cat Dog
1  [Dog, Cow, Tiger]  Dog Cow Tiger
2       [Dog, Tiger]      Dog Tiger
```

Expected Result :

```
   cat  cow  dog  tiger
0    1    0    1      0
1    0    1    1      1
2    0    0    1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the`get_dummies()` function in pandas which you can find the documentation for [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

From the documentation:

```
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
pd.get_dummies(s)

   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```